# Aws SNS notifies Open tracking of email only the first time - Not triggered with subsequent email opens

Tags: amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I have an open and click tracking configured for all the emails sent through Aws SES. Click has been notified to the configured callback URL every time I link in the email has been clicked successfully. Whereas, the opening of email is notified only the first time. Subsequent opening of emails is not notified. Is it the intended behavior or SES?

As I understand, SES adds a hidden tracking pixel inside emails and the loading of images from the trigger is considered as the opening of the email. If that's the case, the pixel should have been opened and notified every time. Can someone please clarify?

Comment: This isn't necessary, end of the day, your email client downloads the 1 pixel image so it has downloaded it and kept in the cache, the hit count won't increase

Comment: Similarly, I have seen in my own application, that the open tracking is completely pointless. Because some of the email providers scan the email before the intended recipient even gets to open it themselves. In this case, the image is downloaded and cached then ... so we never know if the user opens it at all